# ValueError: Layer weight shape (43, 100) not compatible with provided weight shape (412457, 400)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I prepared a small data set for the project. And it gives

> ValueError: Layer weight shape (43, 100) not compatible with provided
>   weight shape (412457, 400)

error. I think there is a problem with tokenizers.

X and Y for train_test_split

```
X = []
sentences = list(titles["title"])
for sen in sentences:
    X.append(preprocess_text(sen))

y = titles['Unnamed: 1']



X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
```

Tokenizer here

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)

X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)

vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1 #vocab_size 43

maxlen = 100

X_train = pad_sequences(X_train, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
X_test = pad_sequences(X_test, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
```

So, my pretrained word2vec model has (412457, 400) shape.

```
from numpy import array
from numpy import asarray
from numpy import zeros

from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
embeddings_dictionary = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('drive/My Drive/trmodel', binary=True)
```

I used my pretrained word2vec model instead of GloVe. (vocab_size: 43, 100, weights from embeddings_dictionary.vectors)

```
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM

model = Sequential()
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 100, weights=[embeddings_dictionary.vectors], input_length=maxlen , trainable=False)
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(LSTM(128))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

> ValueError: Layer weight shape (43, 100) not compatible with provided
>   weight shape (412457, 400)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use pretrained weights, then you have to pass the approprite size parameters to the `Embedding` layer so, that it can assign the pretrained weight matrix to the Embedding layer's weights matrix.

Thus you have to make the following:

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(412457, 400, weights=[embeddings_dictionary.vectors], input_length=maxlen , trainable=False)
```

Before the training you have to change padding conforming it to the `Embedding` layer:

```
maxlen = 400

X_train = pad_sequences(X_train, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
X_test = pad_sequences(X_test, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
```

Comment: It is ok, but error loss is nearly 0.69. In matplotlib graph, train line is straight. Shouldn't the graph be like this? https://prnt.sc/qsfqy9

Comment: @zicxor As I see, the train loss is nearly 0,1 at the 5th epoch. This is a reasonable graph, the only problem, that the model starts to overfit at the 3th epoch, so you have to change the model or/and its hyperparameters to avoid that.